# How can I transfer data from one table to another, overwriting old data?

Tags: sql-server, database, overwrite, transfer

I need some help for transfering data from one table to another.

[image]

As you can see there are 2 databases.

I would like to transfer the table datas "PinterSet" located in the database Contrinex.GPO in the table "PrinterSet" located in the database Contrinex.GPOQA.

There are already datas in the table "PrinterSet" of Contrinex.GPOQA but I would overwrite and put the datas from "PrinterSet" of Contrinex.GPO.

So how can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is your code..

```
truncate table Contrinex.GPOQA.dbo.PrinterSet
go
insert into Contrinex.GPOQA.dbo.PrinterSet
select * from Contrinex.GPO.dbo.PrinterSet
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [Contrinex.GPOQA].dbo.PinterSet
GO
INSERT INTO [Contrinex.GPOQA].dbo.PinterSet (...)
SELECT ...
FROM [Contrinex.GPO].dbo.PinterSet
```

Answer (score 0):

select data from first database table and insert it into the second database table as

```
INSERT INTO GPOQA.PrinterSet SELECT * from GPO.PrinterSet
```

if want some perticular columns then set column names as

```
INSERT INTO GPOQA.PrinterSet a SET a.column1=b.column1,.... SELECT column1,... from GPO.PrinterSet b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sql Server Export functianality, where you can transfer data from one table to another across Database.

Please refer the below link on using the SQL Server Export

http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/feature/The-SQL-Server-Import-and-Export-Wizard-how-to-guide